# Hiding columns with multiple drop down lists

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

i'm new to excel macros and I would like some help with hiding some columns,
I have 2 drop down lists in A2 and A3, both have the options of yes or no. How can I make column C hidden if the No option is chosen in the drop down in A2 and column D disappear if the No option is chosen for the drop down in A3. Then if yes is chosen for both drop downs the columns reappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Worksheet_Change event sub procedure in the worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A3")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        columns(3).entirecolumn.hidden = cbool(lcase(Range("A2").value) = "no")
        columns(4).entirecolumn.hidden = cbool(lcase(Range("A3").value) = "no")
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm assuming that the 'dropdowns' in A2:A3 are data validation lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use events. For a brief tutorial on how to create them, visit: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html

In the example below, I used the `worksheet_calculate` event, which will be triggered everytime the sheet is calculated. You may choose to use the `worksheet_selectionchange`, in case the **Yes/No** dropdown change doesn't trigger a calculation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Yes" Then
    Columns(3).Hidden = False
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "No" Then
        Columns(3).Hidden = True
End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "Yes" Then
    Columns(4).Hidden = False
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = "No" Then
        Columns(4).Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your yes/no hidden/not hidden logic may be reversed. *'make column C hidden if the No option is chosen'*

Comment: True! Sorry about that. Just edited it.